# Customize More Tab in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift3

I need to customize More Tab TableView (or whatever it is) in UITabBarController.

I have this:

[image: This is what I have]

and I need this:

[image: This is what I need]

So I have to:

1. change nav bar color
2. disable Edit button
3. remove empty cells
4. change Tab Bar More icon
5. change background color
6. move cell labels few points to left

When I see this list, it will be maybe much easier to create simple static table view as more tab, but I want to know, if I am able to customize like I need.

Thank you for your time!

Edit: I know how to this things in classic table view or view but I dont know how to access that More Tab in UITabBarController which is automaticcly created, when I have more than 5 tabs.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I have no clue how to access that TableView or whatever is it

Answer (score 1):

**1a) UINavigationBar changes (top bar)**
In you AppDelegate paste in:

```
//make status bar (with time, battery status) white
UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .black

//change color of your navigation bar
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orange
```

**1b)Change UITabBar color:**

```
//make selected tab orange
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orange
```

**2)disable edit button.**
Create an `IBOutlet` of the `UIBarButton` in your `ViewController` or get the reference to it if you create the UIBarButton programatically
Then in `viewDidLoad` type:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   //...
   //gray out UIBarButton
   myBarButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

**3) remove empty cells**
Change UITableView style to Grouped in your IB

**4) change background color of table view**
Change background color of your table view in Interface Builder

**5) Move labels to the left**
Create a custom UITableViewCell, drag and drop a UILabel in and adjust the x value as desired.

**EDIT: change more tab**
I guess that you are trying to modify the text of the more tab. The more tab is automatically generated when you have more than 5 view controllers in your tab bar. In order to display the text in the right language, you have to add a new localization to your project: Click on the blue project icon, go in your project settings and add a new language as shown in the screenshot.
[image: Add localization here]
If you now run the app on a device with the localization you've added (e.g. German, French), the text should be displayed in the correct language.

Comment: And how to create that IBOutlet, when its not in storyboard? That More Tab is automaticaly generated, when I have more than 5 tabs in tab bar. I dont know, how to access it. If I will have it in StoryBoard, I know how to do everypoint of my list.

Comment: @Lifeplus did you find the answer?